# Logic gate on negative signals

Tags: digital-logic, diodes, logic-gates, negative-voltage

I need a logic gate to check if A or B or C is negative voltage (referenced to the ground).
It does not matter if the output is positive or negative logic (as long as it is in positive voltages)

Does this circuit work?

Do you see other solutions or improvements?

One problem I see is that out goes negative if "True".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1J4ZI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT**

I thought about this one too:

easier to compensate the voltage drop of the diodes by tuning the resistances.
and I can invert the logic easily.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBFHCH.png)</sup>

**EDIT**

What I finally did, it works well:

The comparator has built-in reference, just tune the voltage divider to match it. I didn't use hysteresis, the comparator has a built-in hysteresis too, but only few mV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxyEER.png)</sup>

Comment: How many volts of negative voltage are we talking about?

Comment: around +/- 20 V

Comment: And what negative voltage would you consider HIGH and what would you consider LOW? E.g. Va,b,c = +20..-1V would be LOW and -2V..-20V would be HIGH, and -1V..-2V would be undefined? Do you need hysteresis (and what range)? Please update you OP with this information.

Comment: Regarding your second circuit, add a diode in series with the resistor which is now connected to the positive terminal of the opamp and ground, to compensate for the diode drop.

Comment: And you need some hysteresis as MartinF also suggest. Maybe use a Schmitt trigger instead of an opamp?

Comment: Not sure why you put a JFET in your first circuit. An NPN would work just fine there.

Comment: @MartinF, only if voltage is negative, yes for hysteresis (if needed, I'll try without first) I can either use a Schmidt trigger, if I find one with the good specs, or add a positive feedback and make some resistances calculations ;)

Comment: @Huisman, very good idea for the diode

Comment: @DaveTweed yeah they would roughly do the same job here indeed

Comment: No, a JFET won't work at all. Remember, JFETs are strictly depletion-mode. In this circuit, you are using it as a simple diode. In fact, now that I think about it a little more, both versions would need a resistor in series with the emitter/source in order to limit the current when any of the inputs goes negative.

Comment: @DaveTweed if I use a mosfet, the current can only pass through one or the other resistor right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easier if the schematic had reference designators.

Both circuits have issues.  In the upper schematic, (as above) an NPN bipolar such as a 2N4401 or 2N3904 as a common-base amplifier will work more "crisply".  Base to GND, emitter to the diodes, collector to the output.  To prevent the output from going below GND, add another diode in series with the collector and take the output from the diode/1K node.

In the lower schematic, two things.  First, you cannot pull an opamp input 20 V below its negative rail.  Add a diode from the inverting input to GND, anode to GND.  This will clip the input at approx. -0.6 V.  Also, is there a reason why the resistor values are so low?  Power dissipation in the 1K going to the diodes node is 0.4 W, requiring a 1 W part.  Consider raising the values of all resistors to 10K.

This applies to the first schematic also.  You would be pulling approx. 20 mA through the base-emitter junction; that is unnecessarily high and affects long-term reliability.

Second, not all opamps can tolerate even -0.6 V below the negative rail on an input.  Also, not all opamps can drive TTL logic levels when powered from +5 V.  Read all of the datasheets and choose carefully.

Comment: thanks, I will update the answer with the prototype I did, it works well